# Scaling 3rd party programs on small size high resolution display

Tags: dell, screen, display-resolution, xps

I have Dell 9350 (13 inch) and installed Ubuntu 16.04. I am able to use my resolution at `3200 x 1800` but I have small screen so I have to adjust `scale for menu and title bars` setting 1 to 2 in order to have normal window and icon size. Although, there is no problem with size of icon and windows after adjusting, when I download a 3rd party program, I have small screen and I cannot adjust it. What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: As far as I know, ubuntu does not properly support HiDPI screens yet. You can find tutorials online that contain partial workarounds, though, for example http://hgdev.co/optimize-ubuntu-interface-scaling-on-hidpi-displays/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this optimization but it does not work properly for all programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would down your screen resolution.  As a general rule, even for advanced photo and video editing, you're better off to set your screen resolution to a size at which you can conveniently use it, and zoom in.  You might think you'll lose some quality, but it's worth a try.  Frequently high DPI screens are also of a quality that makes them quite good even at more normal resolutions of 1600x1080.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as you said  better solution is reducing screen resolution. I asked this question just to be sure that there is no solution at all. I adjusted it to 1920x1800 compulsorily.